# fluent-plugin-grep: grep A or B than

Tags: grep, fluentd

We are using the fluent-plugin-grep:
This is how my filter looks like

```
<filter **>
  @type grep
  regexp1 level ERROR
</filter>
```

How do I have to change this filter when I want to filter on level ERROR or FATAL? (so not only error)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use OR pattern in regeular expression.
Try following configuration.

```
<filter test.**>
  @type grep
  regexp1 level (ERROR|FATAL)
</filter>
```